# Get rid of setting bar above Gboard keyboard

Tags: 6.0-marshmallow, gboard

> [image: setting bar above keyboard]

How do I get rid of this bar above the Gboard keyboard?

I checked all of its settings, cannot seem to find it.

OnePlus One - Android 6.0.1

Answer (score 7):

Disabling "Show suggestion strip" will also remove the setting bar. However, you won't be able to get any word suggestions though.

[image: Turn off the highlighted option!]

Comment: This is the correct answer. The settings bar *is* the suggestion strip. As soon as you start typing the bar in question starts showing suggestions and the buttons are gone. The buttons are there only when there's nothing to suggest.

Answer (score 1):

Older Gboard doesn't have the setting bar above the keyboard, so downgrading is one of the options.

Here's what Gboard v5.1.18 looks like.

[image] [image: downgrade to 5.1.18.xxxxx]

Answer (score 0):

You need to disable

- Number row
- Google search button
- Suggestion strip

Comment: Disabling the suggestion strip does work, but the users also lose the feature. Disabling the number row doesn't really remove the setting bar, it only makes the keyboard more compact. As of the current version (10.5.04), I can't find the setting for the Google search button though...

Answer (score -1):

You can make it disappear if you set the height of the keyboad to **small**.

Comment: As of the current version (10.5.04), setting the keyboard height to "short" or "extra short" doesn't hide the setting bar.